# C++ ignoring cout redirect for some outputs

Tags: c++, redirect, console, cout

I'm launching my program using the command line and the redirect symbol like so

**program > out.txt**

Is there a way some cout calls can ignore the > operator and still be displayed in the console?

What I want is to have a console menu that will appear in the console, but the rest will get redirected to the file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.

`>` redirects the whole `stdout` stream to a file, not particular writes to that stream. If you want to write to multiple locations, you are to use multiple streams. For example, you could use `stderr`:

```
cout << "redirected" << endl;
cerr << "not redirected" << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's kind of hack, isn't it. I wish there was a stream specifically for this purpose like 

`cout2 << "not redirected" << endl;`

Comment: Actually, there is a stream specifically for writing to console - it's called `cout`. If you want to write some output to file, just create an `std::ofstream`.

Comment: I would love to. This however is a school project and one of the spcification is to have the result written to `stdout` so that the teacher can easily redirect it to a file. The reason I want to do this is because there are extra points to be had for a console menu, but if what you're saying is true, I'm not sure how to combine these.

Comment: @finrod Well, the option with `cerr` still works as `cerr` already is bounded to console. Also, you can create a new stream associated with console. One way I know is `ofstream fout("console$")`, but I'm not sure it's portable.

Answer (score 0):

You could reformat what you are doing and use std::cout when you want to go to stdout, and a `Log` function that writes to a file you specify as the input to the progam.

It might be neater still to have a `Menu` function which displays to std::cout, and the `Log` file able to be configured as to where it ends up.